# Reduction formula of $\int \left(\frac{x^{n-2}}{x^n-1}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing, reduction-formula

I need help in finding reduction formula of the following:

$$ I_n=\int \left(\frac{x^{n-2}}{x^n-1}\right)dx $$

Any hint or a complete solution would be very helpful.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco no, reduction formulas are a thing, often used in contexts such as this. You solve for $I_n$ in general usually by solving $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n-1}$ and computing $I_0$ directly (for example).

Comment: What are the bounds of the integral?

Comment: Nothing major, but this doesn't work for $n = 0$. I'm guessing this is for $n \geq 1$ ?

Comment: Understand you are seeking a recurrence relationship (I had a quick go and couldn't find anything). You can certainly evaluate your integral by factorising the denominator and applying a partial fraction decomposition.  If you would like some further detail on that, let me know and I will post up.

Answer (score 0):

NOT A FULL SOLUTION:

I'm not sure is this will be of help:

\begin{align}
I_n &= \int\frac{x^{n - 2}}{x^n - 1}\:dx = \int \frac{x^n}{x^2\left(x^n - 1\right)}\:dx \\
&=  \int \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{x^n - 1 + 1}{\left(x^n - 1\right)}\:dx = \int \frac{1}{x^2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^n - 1}\right)\:dx = \int \frac{1}{x^2}\:dx - \int \frac{1}{x^2\left(x^n - 1\right)}\:dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{x} -  \underbrace{\int \frac{1}{x^2\left(x^n - 1\right)}}_{J_n}\:dx
\end{align}

So, instead of investigating $I_n$ it may be better to investigate $J_n$ instead.

Alternatively you can easily factor $x^n - 1$ for both odd and even $n$. As above, if you would like detail on that method, let me know and I will post up.